# React router v4 - preserve query params while navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, query-string

I am using React Router v4 for routing in my application. The only issue I have is the query params are ignored while navigation from one route to another. Is there a way to just replace the path and preserve the query params.

Below is my code:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Redirect to="/Route1" />}/>
  <Route exact path='/Route1' component={Route1Comp} />
  <Route path='/Route1/:channel/:id?'
    render={(routeProps) => (
      <AppMain {...routeProps} />
    )}
  />
  <Route exact path='/Route2' component={Route2Comp} />
</Switch>
```

I need the app to have a query param `?isDev=true` and want to retain across. Currently if I am on `localhost:3000/Route1Comp?isDev=true` and navigate to `Route2Comp` using `Link` then the entire path is replaced along with query params.

Comment: Did you get a solution? I'm also getting same issue

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the Link component from react-router to include the search params by default like

```
const ExtendedLink = ({ to, children, location}) => {
   return <Link to={{
               pathname: to,
               search: location.search
          }}>{children}</Link>
}

export default withRouter(ExtendedLink)
```

and then use it instead of `Link`

```
<ExtendedLink to='/Route1'>Route 1</ExtendedLink>
```